# How to open program with key input

Tags: python-3.x

I want to open the calculator program when I type "Open calculator " . I researched a lot , but didn't get the answer I wanted.Can anyone please answer my question.

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Is this calculator made by you within the Python program or is it an external application installed on your system?

Comment: External .It is the default windows calculator.

Comment: In that case you can use the `os` module. Posting code in the answer

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this. One way would be access the cmd using Python which can be done by using `os` module. When you try to open the calculator from your command prompt, you probably type `calc`. Instead of manually doing this, you can have your Python code do it for you, this is how:

```
import os
os.system('calc')
```

The second way is very similar to the first one, except that this method opens another command prompt window so the window in which you're running the python code is not disturbed.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("calc",stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,shell=True)
```